# Change contenteditable div to false in downloaded html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with divs where the user inputs some information which then can download to save a copy. It's using `<div contenteditable="true">...</div>` and when the html is downloaded I would like the divs to not be editable anymore so that the text that has been written stays printed. So I would like to change `contenteditable="true"` to `contenteditable="false"` just in the downloaded html (and keep it "true" on the website). How can I implement it within the code below? Many thanks.

```
function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click(); 
}

var fileName =  'text-' + getFormattedTime() + '.html'

function getFormattedTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var d = today.getDate();
    return y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
}

$('#downloadLink').click(function(){
    downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'wrapper','text/html');
});
```

Comment: Can't manage to make it work, I'm quite newbie to js

Comment: OK, I posted an answer which should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that worked for me is an onClick event that temporarily switches the contenteditable value from "true" to "false" for 1 second; just enough to download the divs as uneditable text and keep them editable on the website.

```
function editableTimeout() {
  var x = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
    var editableDivs = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]");
for(var i=0; i<editableDivs.length; i++)
    editableDivs[i].setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
  setTimeout(() => {
     var editableDivs = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=false]");
for(var i=0; i<editableDivs.length; i++)
    editableDivs[i].setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Element.removeAttribute()**

You want to removed the [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) attribute from the div when the user clicks to download. You can do this by modifying your code as shown so that it calls [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) and the div then prevents further editing.

**From:**

```
var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
```

**To:**

```
var el = document.getElementById(elId);
el.removeAttribute("contenteditable");
var elHtml = el.innerHTML;
```

The code won't work correctly as an SO snippet, but you can try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhuteng6/) to understand how it works.

**Update:**

OP asked how to remove the contenteditable attribute from all elements on the page, rather than just one. And this is easily done using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find all contenteditable elements and removing the attribute from each one like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]").forEach(function(el) 
{ 
    el.removeAttribute("contenteditable")
});
```

Run the snippet to see how this works:

```js
removeAll.onclick = function() {

    document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]").forEach(function(el) { 
        el.removeAttribute("contenteditable")
    });

};
```

```css
.container > div {
    height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid dimgray;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
}

.container > div[contenteditable=true] {
   color: lime;
   background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="removeAll">Remove All</button>

<div class="container">

  <div contenteditable="true">A</div>
  <div contenteditable="true">B</div>
  <div contenteditable="true">C</div>
  <div contenteditable="true">D</div>
  <div contenteditable="true">E</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Cool. Does it work only with an id given to the contenteditable div? What I have are multiple contenteditable divs without an id or class, wrapped inside a normal div with id="wrapper".

Comment: @redibis - Your code works with one div at a time where you supply the id.  Yet, see the updated answer for a way to remove the contenteditable attribute from every element on the page.

Comment: Thank you. This is removing the attribute from the website too, can it be in the downloaded html only?

Comment: Yes, just modify the selector to remove contenteditable from sections rather than the whole page.  For example, document.querySelectorAll("#wrapper [conenteditable]") would only remove them from a section of the page with id="wrapper".  You can scope it to whatever fits your requirements.

Comment: I don't understand how to apply that to the downloaded html only, and leave the divs inside the #wrapper on the page still editable.

Comment: The answer would depend on the page structure and how it is created and used, but the question doesn't include enough of those details to make a recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

In easiest way I will try something like  this ))
elHtml.replace('contenteditable="true"', 'contenteditable="false"')